# How to show in address bar www.domain.com instead of www.domain.com/something

Tags: opencart

I have website made on opencart CMS, it is one page website, so I made redirect in home.tpl on page www.domain.com/promo (it is product page)

```
<?php
header("Location: /promo");
exit();
?>
```

Now when someone opens www.domain.com he see www.domain.com/promo.

How to make him see only www.domain.com?

Answer (score 0):

Go to the `index.php` file and look for the router coding, it should look similar to the code below:

```
$action = new Action('common/home');
```

You will then have to change `'common/home'` to the location of the page you created within Opencart.

For example: to navigate to the login page we will have to change it to `'account/login'`